# BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug === The path does not exist Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255

Tags: flutter-ios

Im getting the following error when running my flutter app as iOS. And when i run it as Android on Android emulator, it builds successfully and it works fine. I don't know whats wrong with the iOS part.

**BUILD FAILED**

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The path  does not exist
    Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the error by doing the following:

1.Open your project in Xcode by right clicking the Runner.xcworkspace folder, then go down to Flutter and select it, and then select Open iOS module in Xcode.

2.Then select Runner(or the name of your project in Xcode) by going to show project navigator.

3.Then under Project Runner(or the name of your project in Xcode), select info.

4.Then under Configuration, set Runner to Generated, do that for all three(Debug, Release, Profile).

After that try to build again, and you will be able to build successfully, then you can run your app again.

I hope this helps someone else out there who is facing this kinda error.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved that issue by deleting "Runner.xcodepro" , "Pods" , "Runner.xcworkspace" and "Podfile" then executed "flutter create ." in project root directory. Build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem happened after you had updated your flutter, creating a new flutter project from scratch and transfer your work to the new project might be the only way out.

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56642